# Plugging a MIDI Device in a MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, midi

What options are there for plugging a MIDI-device that offers only a standard [DIN-5 MIDI connector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aDIN-5_Diagram.svg) into a MacBook Pro?

The marketing print on the box of my [Rock Band 3 Wireless Keyboard](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003RS19N4) talks about plugging the keyboard into a computer for use as a general MIDI instrument when not playing Rock Band, but there's no cables inside the box to accomplish this, and again, the only port it offers is a DIN-5 port.

Comment: A wise man once said, "standards are for unoriginal losers"

Comment: I hear that "wise man" is still at the top of a mountain trying to start his BBQ with non-standard matches...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple and cheap: [USB to MIDI connector](http://www.meritline.com/usb-to-midi-adapter-cable---p-42337.aspx). If you need to plug in more than one MIDI device there are [dedicated MIDI interfaces](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0002J1PNK). Additionally, many A/D audio [interfaces](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001DDU8PU) - that you might also use to record input from analog devices like guitars or microphones - include MIDI ins/outs.

Without more information about your specific needs I can't say the products I linked to are the best choice, but they are representative of the vast array of options for plugging a MIDI device into your MacBook Pro.

Comment: I'm using the Rock Band 3 Wireless Keyboard. I added a little blurb about it into the question. Though I think your MIDI->USB convertor will be good enough.

Comment: Yep, it will work with any of the methods I suggested. You just need a MIDI cable and any of the the MIDI to USB converter suggestions above, the USB to MIDI connector being the cheapest.

Comment: Definitely buying a straight MIDI->USB cable. Thanks.